# How to render a UIView with all subviews and layout to a UIImage using UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uiimage

I need to render my UIView to a UIImage with all subviews and its layout. It should be like a real snapshot of this view.
I tried so many ways but they returned me a wrong image. In some cases it didn't has any subviews in other cases it didn't has layout.

I created my view like this:

```
func viewWithImageAndText(text: String, image: UIImage?) -> UIView {
    guard let image = image else { return UIView() }
    
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.tintColor = .white
    
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = text
    label.textColor = .white

    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 2
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
    ])
    
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
    
    return view
}
```

And I tried these ways:

1.

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.bounds.size)
let image = renderer.image { ctx in
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

2. 

```
func getImage(from view:UIView) -> UIImage? {
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, true, UIScreen.main.scale)
    guard let context =  UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
    view.layer.render(in: context)
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()   
}
```

3. 

```
func asImage() -> UIImage? {
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
    return renderer.image { rendererContext in
        layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
    }
}
```

And etc.

Does anyone know a really working solution?

Comment: Add this line before set constraint ```stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false```

Comment: thx, it doesn't help

Comment: set view frame same as self.view.frame and use your first approch.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't want to depend on some superview. I want't to create a view with custom size

Comment: Then it works fine after setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  and passing the same size with UIView object and UIGraphicsImageRenderer size / frame

Comment: But it already uses its frame and size. Could you explain or write in code? I still don't understand what do you mean

Comment: Check this code : https://gist.github.com/kishanraja/c004a1112f7f36ecccf02df5d238b535

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I checked it in the pet project. I set UIView and UIImageView. I init UIView with viewWithImageAndText(...) and also I try to init UIImageView with its shapshot as it was in your git. But I see empty UIImageView. UIView has view and it looks good

Comment: Have you used all code that I shared? Because I shared after testing and work just fine.

Comment: sure, I did like it was been in your git

Comment: IF possible please add your demo project.

Comment: I added my code and screens to your git as a comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238560/discussion-between-raja-kishan-and-vyacheslavbakinkskiy).

Comment: The chat has disappeared, what was the result?